# Assembly x86-64: default in switch statement

Tags: assembly, switch-statement, x86-64

I am trying to mimic the following code, which should print 1 2 in assembly:

```
    a=1
    switch(a) {
            default: print 1;
            case 2: print 2;
    }
```

and this is what I have:

```
    movq $1, a
    pushq a
    popq %rdx
    cmp $1, %rdx
    jne if_0
    jmp if_1
if_0:
    movq $1, %rsi
    pushq %rsi
    movq $format, %rdi
    popq %rsi
    pushq %rbp
    call printf
    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp
    jmp if_2
if_1:
    movq $2, %rsi
    pushq %rsi
    popq %r11
    cmpq %rdx, %r11
    je if_2
    jne if_3
if_2:
    movq $2, %rsi
    pushq %rsi
    movq $format, %rdi
    popq %rsi
    pushq %rbp
    call printf
    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp
    jmp if_4
if_3:
if_4:
    jmp switch_0
```

At the top, I am only comparing the variable to 1 because I'm unsure of what to do. How can I look ahead and see that a is not equal to 2 before doing the default case?

Comment: It's unclear what you have a problem with. You don't have to check the cases in the order listed in the source. Obviously you want to leave `default` last, if nothing else matched.

Comment: Several languages enforce `default:` as last thing in `case`, so your example feels invalid, but let's say it's possible. Other way to write that example is `if (2 != a) { print 1; } print 2;` ... but as `a = 1` always, you can just do `{ print 1; print 2; }` without any logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are acting as a compiler, so you can "look ahead" at all the cases and see that the `default` case is taken if the switch is *not* `2`.

Or, if you are an even shrewder "compiler", you can see that the code is always going to print `1 2` and not do any comparisons at all.

Comment: "the code is always going to print 1" only when the number is not equal to 2, though, right?

Comment: @anc:  The code shown always uses the value `1`.  I don't see any variability in the code so it doesn't actually need to mess around with a value at all:  just print the result.

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems overcomplicated.

Look at C code and corresponding ASM code

```
int printer(int a) 
{
    switch(a) 
    {
            default: printf("%s","1");
            case 2: printf("%s","2");
    }
}
```

Yes - I know you set a=1 - but than it doesn't make any sense to compare if you know result in advance. Below non-optimized ASM result - there is putchar because string is one letter - but this could be changed to printf as desired.

```
printer(int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        cmp     eax, 2
        je      .L5
        mov     edi, 49
        call    putchar
.L5:
        mov     edi, 50
        call    putchar
        nop
        leave
        ret
```

With optimization it is even simpler

```
printer(int):
        cmp     edi, 2
        jne     .L13
        mov     edi, 50
        jmp     putchar
.L13:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, 49
        call    putchar
        mov     edi, 50
        add     rsp, 8
        jmp     putchar
```

You probably noticed gcc trick - it removed stack frame and ret instruction altogether.